# Why do I get "Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I created my first Flutter project with `flutter create app01`, and when I try to run it on my physical device I get this error:

```
[+14236 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[+1928375 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +19 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +4 ms] A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
[   +2 ms] > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
[   +4 ms]    > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar
(org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50)
[   +3 ms]       > Could not get resource
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.ja
r'.
[   +2 ms]          > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 36,615,572; received:
19,922,800)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First close the IDE or the coding app and goto cmd run **flutter doctor** if you it says
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er4Pa.png)

then type flutter doctor --android-licenses

continue the steps it askes you by pressing y for yes and more

Comment: I did, but all the categories are green, especially " Android toolchain", It says "no issues found!".